# Mocha js import React Component Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

I am trying to import a React Component in my test file.

```
import { SecondCDS } from '.\SecondCDS.js'.
```

I am getting the following error

```
C:\Users\bendind\example\node_modules\babel- core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:591  
throw err;
^

SyntaxError: C:/Users/bendind/example/app/SecondCDS.js: Unexpected token (617:17)
```

The code at that line is:

```
result.push(<CurveRow data={data.arr[i]}/>);
```

So I am basically adding to an array.

I do not get the above error when transpiling with Babel and running my application.

Though, I now face the problem in mocha.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does your `--compilers` flag look like when you run mocha?

Comment: So I resolved this issue, I hadn't added react in the .babelrc file.